# Render multiple components based on data attributes

Tags: reactjs, dom, reason, reason-react

On ReasonReact, if I want to render a specific element on a HTML element by `id` I can use the built-in function `renderToElementWithId(ReasonReact.reactElement, Dom.element)`, for example:

```
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<MyComponent />, "myComponent");
```

I have multiple `<input />` HTML tags, and I want it to be rendered in every `<input />` which has a specific data attribute. More specifically, I want that each `input` which has `data-type="tags"` on it be rendered by `<MyComponent />`. On Javascript we could do something like `document.querySelectorAll("[data-type=tags]")` and iterate the result rendering the components.

Although, I can't find anywhere in the documentation of ReasonReact nor BSB about how to do this. Can someone help me?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReasonReact has a `ReactDOMRe.render` function that takes a `Dom.element`. You can then define `querySelectorAll` yourself, if you wish:

```
[@bs.val] [@bs.scope "document"]
external querySelectorAll : string => Dom.element = "";

querySelectorAll("[data-type=tags]")
|> Js.Array.forEach(element => ReactDOMRe.render(<MyComponent />, element));
```

Or you can use [bs-webapi](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator), which gives you `querySelectorAll` along with a whole heap of other DOM functions if you need them.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be really neccessary to use "unsafe" code (JS interop) or if there was a built-in funcionários for this. Thanks.

Comment: That's why I pointed towards bs-webapi. That's safe, but you might find that the DOM API wasn't designed to be safe, and that it's a bit cumbersome to deal with it safely.